# Broke ROS dependencies, not sure how to fix

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that I broke ROS dependencies somehow and I don't know how to fix it. I had a few working packages that have compiled fine in the past, and now when I try to catkin_make I get CMake errors for every basic ros dependency depending on which one shows up first in the first package in the workspace.

The output is as follows:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
of the following names:

roscppConfig.cmake
roscpp-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 antenna/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'roscpp'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the 
package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
of the following names:

roscppConfig.cmake
roscpp-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
antenna/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

I've tried everything I could think of like sourcing, deleting individual packages (it did not change anything), I even reinstalled ros completely but same error. I also tried updating rosdep.

Any help is appreciated, I think I'm missing something small somewhere.

Edit: The output of

```
$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
```

is:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic
```

I should also I tried recreating the packages with the dependencies as well but still the same issue. So I think the issue is rooted independently of the packages.

Edit again, the output of

```
dpkg -l | grep ros-kinetic-roscp
```

is:

```
 ii  ros-kinetic-roscpp                            1.12.14-0xenial-20180824-091453-0800                                amd64        
 roscpp is a C++ implementation of ROS.
 ii  ros-kinetic-roscpp-core                       0.6.11-0xenial-20180824-083916-0800                                 amd64        
 Underlying data libraries for roscpp messages.
 ii  ros-kinetic-roscpp-serialization              0.6.11-0xenial-20180824-083414-0800                                 amd64        
 roscpp_serialization contains the code for serialization as described in MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes.
 ii  ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits                     0.6.11-0xenial-20180824-083319-0800                                 amd64        
 roscpp_traits contains the message traits code as described in MessagesTraits.
 ii  ros-kinetic-roscpp-tutorials                  0.7.1-0xenial-20180824-100457-0800                                  amd64        
This package attempts to show the features of ROS step-by-step, including using messages, servers, 
parameters, etc.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319379/broke-ros-dependencies,-not-sure-how-to-fix/) by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-24**:
Hi,
Can you please edit the question with the output of

```
echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
```

**Comment by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on 2019-03-25**:
@janindu Edited the question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-25**:
@hillripper21: do you still have ROS pkgs installed? What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep ros-kinetic-roscpp` fi?

**Comment by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on 2019-03-25**:
@gvdhoorn edited

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-25**:
It looks like you have everything installed. How about

```
catkin clean
```

and then

```
catkin build
```

within your workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried that before too. I just reinstalled ROS for a third time and it worked this time... honestly not sure what was going on. If anyone else runs into this just try reinstalling ROS and make sure everything is completely purged. Thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) with karma: 26 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0